# Render PDF in Landscape on API Version 33 or above? (Works on 26)

Tags: visualforce, api-version

My visualforce page is rendered as a pdf with

`renderAs=pdf`

`@page{size: landscape;}`

Unfortunately, this setting works only with API Version 26.0 and not 33.0. Is there a known alternative/workaround to have my page displayed in landscape without changing my API Version?

Comment: try this @media print{@page {size: landscape}}

Comment: @Ratan Does not work! Tried `@media print` `@media screen`

Comment: How is your CSS being placed in your page? I have noticed that on API versions > 26, Salesforce is much picker about CSS placement for pdf rendering.

Comment: @D.S. Yes, it does not wrap words or apply CSS properties that do not fall under CSS2.1.